# ios6 EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0) error

Tags: ios6, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, exc-bad-access, back

I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0) error (the address equals is another not 0x0 but I assume a number related to my project).

This error occurs when going "back" to the main VC in a Navigation Controller system. The set up is as follows:

[image]

**View Controller - MyConnection is the main ViewController**. There are tableviewcells and a tab bar on this VC. The tableviewcells will take you to either the **Choose Server VC** or the **Choose Test Type VC**. The one button on the tab bar takes you to **Preferences VC**.

This all works fine, you can go to and back with no issues.

The Preferences VC also has tablecells which also take the user to the Choose Server and Choose Test Type VCs. My error occurs when going from either Choose Server or Choose Test Type, back to Preferences and then back to the main VC. **It crashes upon** going back to the main VC and gives the error described above. Sadly the debugger doesn't give much more information. I have deduced that the viewWillAppear code in the main VC is being called and when reloading the table data it crashes.

Any idea what may be going wrong?

UPDATE:

Using the debugger some more it appears the cellForRowAtIndexPath isn't being called when returning. Any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

After reading a few other posts related to cellForRowAtIndexPath not being called I tried adding:

```
self.navigationController.delegate= self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

to my viewWillAppear in the main ViewController. This solved the problem.